# update samba using apt-get and automatically keep local smb.conf

Tags: linux, debian, samba

I have a bunch of systems running debian 8.4.0 which can be user updated through a web interface. The system then fetches an update from our server and runs an update script. Logging in remotely is not a viable option.

I have to install a samba update, but this asks for user input to choose whether to keep local smb.conf or use the new one provided by the update.

How can I automate this so that no user input is requested, ie, so that i can do this from a script? The current line i use is:

```
apt-get -y --force-yes --install-suggests --install-recommends \
install samba
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22957939/how-to-answer-an-apt-get-configuration-change-prompt-on-travis-ci-in-this-case/23048987

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out that what i wanted to do is actually an "unattended update". We can pass options that apt-get will forward to dpkg for individual packages:

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get -y --force-yes --install-recommends install \
-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confdef" \
-o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confold" \
samba
```

where:

- `--force-confdef` - upgrade the configuration file if there are no local changes, and
- `--force-confold` - otherwise, preserve the existing configuration file

This was of great help: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/perform_an_unattended_installation_of_a_debian_package.html